# Firebase cloud messaging "Registration failed - push service error" on Electron and node-webkit

Tags: firebase, electron, firebase-cloud-messaging, node-webkit, nwjs

I am trying to implement Firebase web cloud messaging on node-webkit (NWJS) application, but when I try to get a token its returning a error: "Registration failed - push service error". Here is the code snippet I am using to get the token after authentication.

```
messaging.requestPermission()
  .then(function() {
    console.log("have Permission");
    return messaging.getToken();
  })
  .then(function(token) {
    console.log(token);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log("Error occured");
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Seeing the same issue

Comment: @DarkNeuron No still facing the same issue

Comment: I've noticed that this error is only present in Opera for me, not in Chrome. So in my case its probably a bug in Opera.

Comment: Experiencing this issue on practically every Android device running Chrome ):
Btw this issue in my case originates with the `getToken()` method not requestPermission().